# How to improve the PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) Quality for document based PMI

Tags: machine-learning, embeddings

Generating word embeddings from the PMI is well understood and known to be equivalent to SGNS (skipgram negative-sampling) under certain conditions. I was able to get good quality word embedding using this approach for various corpora as well.

In the above approach, the concept of document does not play a role:
$$pmi_{xy} = log\frac{p(x,y)} {p(x) p(y)}$$
where the probabilities are calculated across the whole corpus.

However, I am trying to generate document embeddings as well as word embeddings, so I used a document-based PMI approach, as outlined here : [Word Tensors](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2017/10/25/word-tensors/). In this approach, we consider the probability of the skipgram $(x,y)$ appears in document $d$: $$pmi_{xyd} = log \frac{p(x,y,d)}{p(x)p(y)p(d)}$$

I decompose the 3-mode tensor to get the document embedding along with the word embeddings.

Unfortunately, this approach does not work as well as the document-agnostic PMI approach and generates low-quality word embeddings. Further investigation reveals that the PMI information is not of good quality: even for a highly correlated skipgram (e.g., "husband" and "wife"), because we are only counting its frequency within each document (the $p(x,y,d)$ part) rather than across the whole corpus, and because single document is of limited length and provides limited contextual information, this highly correlated skipgram cannot get a high enough PMI value to distinguish itself from those skipgrams that are only weakly correlated.

So my question is: how do I improve the quality of the PMI information when we take documents into account and want to generate document embeddings? Is there research along this line? Thanks a lot to anyone who could point me to some relevant works!

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow, yangsuli! This seems like an interesting question, but I think you might get a better response on a machine-learning focused Stackexchange site, such as ai.stackexchange.com . On that site people may be more familiar with the material you're asking about, and more interested in the applied aspects.

Comment: Your idea in the last paragraph - aggregate word embeddings into document embeddings - is one way to conceptualize the attention mechanism that makes the neural transformer architecture tick. I'm not sure this is well understood from an information theoretic perspective though due to the sparsity issue that you identified. I think one would have to work with probability distributions on the embedding space rather than the discrete word / document space in order to overcome this.

Comment: @MartinM.W. Thanks for the pointer. Since someone already responded via comments, I think I will wait a few days before cross listing it on ai.stackexchange.com.